# Directory special permission problem

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod

When I write:
chmod g=rws,u=rwx,o=rx folder_name

I get:
drwxrwSr-x

But S is not the same as s, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specified the `s` bit for the group without the `x` bit. Executable and setgid are separate bits, the `ls` command just combines them into a single letter to gain space. You need

```
chmod g=rwxs,u=rwx,o=rx folder_name
```

i.e. `chmod 2775 folder_name`. You did `chmod 2765 folder_name`.

`S` means setxid without executable, it's in uppercase because that's rarely useful and likely a sign of a mistake that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` display has a fixed-size display field for the mode (a.k.a. permission bits), so it will show `s` (or `t`, for the restricted deletion flag – the so-called "sticky bit") if the executable-bit is present (since it is normally expected to be present on the either directories or executable files on which these bits are meaningful), and (capital) `S` (or `T`) if it is absent. `chmod` has no such constraint, so it simply assigns a letter to each mode bit.